# Mapping views with hibernate but avoid table generation in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I want to map my views and use JPA to make queries.

Let's say my view is the following:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "active_task_view")
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ActiveTaskViewEntity {

    private long id;
    private String taskName;
    private String workflowName;
    private String userName;
    private LocalDate createdAt;
    private LocalDate updatedAt;

}
```

I have set applications.properties allowing to generate entities:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:import.sql
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

My issue is the following: the views are created as tables. I put entities in a specific package and tables in other. I don't know how i could define what tables should be generated and which entities should be just used as mapping.

Actually, views should be present in a import.sql file in the classpath (not yet implemented).

Comment: Consider hbm2ddl as a quick start/trivial solution... Though you could differentiate hbm2ddl settings in *different* "persistence units", (i think) with "script init" or "high lvl migration" you are better/cheaper off... [1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization), [2](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-jpa-entity-to-view-or-sql-query-with-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I simply set the base package for entity scan...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "fr.mycompany.app.entity.table" })
public class WsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My views are mapped in a different package such as fr.mycompany.app.entity.view
It didn't generate my views in my database. It seems to be the easiest way for this.
The views are handled in a sql file for init.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of "options" (my own preference is to use liquibase instead):

I. mark you entities with `@Subselect` instead of `@Table`, something like:

```
@Subselect("select * from active_task_view")
```

II. implement `org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaFilterProvider`, I believe that should look like:

HBN part:

```java
import org.hibernate.mapping.Table;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.DefaultSchemaFilter;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.DefaultSchemaFilterProvider;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaFilter;

public class SchemaFilterProviderCustom extends DefaultSchemaFilterProvider {

    @Override
    public SchemaFilter getCreateFilter() {
        return new DefaultSchemaFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean includeTable(Table table) {
                // logic here
                return true/false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

boot part:

```java
@Component
public class SchemaFilterProviderCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put(
                AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_FILTER_PROVIDER,
                new SchemaFilterProviderCustom()
        );
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I didn't try this ... I found out a dummy solution for my case. I simply annotated my Springboot main class with @EntityScan(basePackages = { "mypackage.entity.table" }), the views are in entity.view package ... and it works fine :)